# I cant access json data returned from a different function, its saying its undefined

Tags: javascript, json, function, async-await, fetch-api

I'm trying to get json data from the Coin Market Cap api, the fetch request is successful but when i call it in my second function to get just the price data its returning undefined.

```
const getBitcoinData = async () => {
  try {
    const response = await fetch(btcURL, {
      method: 'GET',
      headers: {
        'X-CMC_PRO_API_KEY': apiKey,
        'Accept': 'application/json',
      },
    });

    if (!response.ok) {
      throw new Error('Network response was not ok');
    }

    const json = await response.json();
    console.log(json);
    return json;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error:', error);
    throw error;
  }
};

export const btcPriceData = () => {
  getBitcoinData()
  .then(bitcoinData => {
    console.log(bitcoinData)
    
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.error('failed to get btc data', error);
  });
};
```

I tried passing it as a parameter, I've searched on here and found nothing and chatgpt said "your code appears to be correct". I'm sorry if this is a shitty post and an easy fix I'm stupid for not seeing, its my first real project and first time actually posting on here.

Comment: try to parse it again in the console

Comment: The output of `console.log(json)` should be the same as `console.log(bitcoinData)`. Is that not what you're seeing?

Comment: @LieutenantDan i get a syntax error when i parse it again. [SyntaxError: JSON Parse error: Unexpected character: o]

Comment: @Barmar no console.log(json) returns the data i need, console.log(bitcoinData) is undefined.

Comment: I don't see how that can be happening. Using `.then()` is the correct way to get the return value from an async function.

Comment: Are you sure you have `return json` in `getBitcoinData`?

Comment: Maybe you have console.log(btcPriceData()) somewhere.  That would give you undefined.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your code looks mostly correct, but there is one issue in the `btcPriceData` function. Since `getBitcoinData` is an asynchronous function, it returns a promise. In order to access the resolved value of the promise, you need to use the `then` method or `async/await` syntax.

In your `btcPriceData` function, you are not returning anything, which is why it is returning `undefined`. To fix this, you can modify your code as follows:

```
javascript
export const btcPriceData = () => {
  return getBitcoinData() // Add 'return' here
    .then(bitcoinData => {
      console.log(bitcoinData);
      // Process the bitcoinData further if needed
      // For example, return just the price data:
      return bitcoinData.price;
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.error('failed to get btc data', error);
      throw error;
    });
};
```

Now, when you call `btcPriceData`, it will return a promise that resolves to the `bitcoinData` object. You can further process this data or extract specific information from it.

Remember to handle the promise returned by `btcPriceData` using `then` or `async/await` syntax when you want to access the resolved value:

```
javascript
btcPriceData()
  .then(price => {
    console.log(price);
    // Use the price data
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.error('Failed to get BTC price data', error);
  });
```

Make sure to adjust the code according to your requirements and how you want to use the data.